# Prove that: $\varepsilon$ is a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $E$ be a Banach function space, $X$ be a Banach space endowed with the norm $\parallel \cdot \parallel$. Set
>   $\varepsilon:=\varepsilon(\mathbb{R},X)=\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X: f \text{ is strongly measurable and } \parallel f(\cdot)\parallel \in E \}$
>   (modulo $\lambda$- nullfunctions ) endowed with the norm
>   $\parallel f\parallel_{\varepsilon}:=\parallel\parallel f(\cdot)\parallel\parallel_{E}. $
>   Prove that: $\varepsilon$ is a Banach space.

I take a function sequence $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots\}$ in the space $\varepsilon$ satisfying the Cauchy condition: For every $a>0$ ,there exists $n_0$ such that $(m,n>n_0\Rightarrow \parallel f_m-f_n\parallel_{\varepsilon}<a$ and I need to find a function $f\in\varepsilon$ s.t. $f_m\rightarrow f$ in $\varepsilon$. Now, because $\parallel(f_m-f_n)(.)\parallel \geq \parallel f_m(.)\parallel-\parallel f_n(.)\parallel$ on whole $\mathbb{R}$, the function sequence $\{\parallel f_n\parallel\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the Cauchy sequence in $E$. So, it tends to a limit in $E$. Set this limit $g(.)$. I should choose $f$ s.t. $\parallel f(t)\parallel=g(t) \forall t\in \mathbb{R}$, but i don't know how to choose $f$. Could someone suggest me, please?

Comment: what is (are) your  question(s) ?

Comment: @Fred: I'm sorry, and i edited.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a Banach function space?

Comment: Here, https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Banach_function_space where $\Omega=\mathbb{R}, \Sigma $ is Borel $\sigma-$algebra, $\muy $ is Lebesgue measure.